# Hot to find out if it is first user log in with django social?

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I am building an app, witch django social, and i need to do some stuff when user register, but i can not find out whether this is his first log in or not, how can i do that without alter user db, and without last_login == date_joined (because i think it's pretty dirty way, tell me if not)
Also sorry for my bad english in some places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the first user login, last_login field will be NULL. You can override the LoginView and form_valid, for example:

```
class LoginView(auth_views.LoginView):
    """Renders the client login page."""

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Security check complete. Log the user in."""
        auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())
        
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated and not self.request.user.date_joined:
            # do your stuff
            
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Also, make sure to add this view to the login url in your urls.py

Comment: Actualy i tried this, and even when it is the first login, last_login is not null it's already set

Comment: @Andreyka You could also define a custom user model, and add a boolean for if the 'stuff that has to be done' is done. Then in your loginview you can check if that boolean is true/false and 'do your stuff' if so.

Comment: If i do that, will it be necessary to redo all my previous interactions with user model?

Comment: I think so, yes. Another solution is to create a separate model with a onetoonefield to user and store that value there. Then you don't have to change the user.